# Python Srceenshot with PhantomJS in Kali

Tags: python, phantomjs, webpage-screenshot

I want to take a screenshot with Selenium PhantomJS, as the Chrome and Firefox --headless options are much slower. Here is my code for it:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
driver.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')
driver.quit()
```

The .png file this creates is 0 bytes, which is thus useless.

The following code on the other hand works just fine, although much slower, as the --headless option for Chrome opens and closes the browser.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = options, executable_path = r'C:\Users\a\Selenium\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
driver.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')
```

Comment: maybe you need "--disable-gpu" as argument also if you are using windows... here in documentation https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will try that for windows, but I'm more interested in why the screenshot taking doesn't work with PhantomJS in Kali.